# Proving that every countable metric space is disconnected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Any hints on how I should go about this? Thanks.

Comment: Try to prove every connected metric space with at least two points is uncountable

Answer (score 16):

The statement is false if $|X|=1$, so *countable* here is probably supposed to be understood as *countably infinite*.

HINT: Let $X$ be the space, and let $x,y\in X$ with $x\ne y$. Let $r=d(x,y)>0$. Use the fact that $X$ is countable to show that there must be an $s\in(0,r)$ such that

$$\{z\in X:d(x,z)=s\}=\varnothing\;.$$

If $B(x,s)=\{z\in X:d(x,z)<s\}$, show that $B(x,s)$ and $X\setminus B(x,s)$ are non-empty open sets in $X$, and conclude that $X$ is not connected.

Comment: Why not (finite and not $|X|=1$ and not empty)?

Comment: @BCLC: (Apparently I never saw this one.) The result is true for every countable metric space of cardinality greater than $1$, but I was sticking to the statement of the result in the question. Unfortunately, *countable* has two meanings in common use: properly it means *of cardinality at most* $\omega$ (or $\aleph_0$, if you prefer), but some use it to mean *or cardinality exactly* $\omega$, and for the result to be true as stated, the word must have the narrower sense.

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean totally disconnected? In that case, take two points $x, y$ with $d(x, y) = a$. Then, since there are only countably many points in the space, and there are uncountably many real numbers less than $a$, there must be a distance $b < a$ such that there are no points *exactly* at a distance $b$ from $x$.

That means that the ball around $x$ with radius $b$ is both open and closed, and so is its complement. Thus you have partitioned the space into two disjoint clopen sets, one containing each point. Since the points were arbitrary, this means that the space is totally disconnected.

Comment: Thank you! One question though: why exactly is the ball around x with radius b both open and closed? Singleton sets are always closed, I get that, but why is it open as well?

Comment: What I've shown is not so much that the singletons are open, but more that no two points are in the same connected component. When I say "No points are at a distance $b$ from $x$", I mean _exactly_ $b$. There might be points $z$ such that $d(x, z) < b$. The main point, however, is that the $b$-ball centered at $x$ is both open and closed at the same time, since $\{z | d(x, z) < b\}$ and $\{z | d(x, z) \leq b\}$ consist of exactly the same points. Thus no point outside the ball is in the same connected component as $x$. Since $y$ is arbitrary, no point but $x$ is in $x$'s connected component.

Comment: The points of $\mathbb Q$ are dense in the real numbers.So no, you can _never_ find such a $b$.

Comment: @alexis Yes, I can find such a $b$. Given a rational point $p$, the balls of radius (for instance) $\frac{\pi}{n}$ centered on $p$ are clopen, since the boundary is empty. For any other rational number $q$, choose $n$ so that the ball around $x$ is small enough not to contain $q$ (then the corresponding $\frac{\pi}{n}$ is my $b$). Thus you have a clopen neighbourhood around $x$ not containing $y$, proving that they are not part of the same connected component.

Comment: I of course mean $p$ and $q$ in the last sentence in my previous comment, not $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I (mis)read that to say there would be no points at distance $< b$, but you meant exactly $b$. Makes sense now. (To show it's closed, you need to point out that the ball from $q$ to the separating point is disjoint and also open).